# Remove Bin DLL Files from within a ASP.NET App?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I remove Bin DLL Files from within a ASP.NET App?

When I try it on IIS 7.5, it says "Permission denied".

I wrote a codebehind script, to remove DLL files from within the bin directory. The code snippet is as below:

```
string[] filesList = Directory.GetFiles(System.Web.HttpRuntime.BinDirectory, "*.dll");
foreach (string f in filesList)
{
    try
    {
        File.Delete(f);
        app.Context.Response.Write("R: " + f + "\n");
    }
    catch (IOException deleteError)
    {
        app.Context.Response.Write(deleteError.Message);
    }
}
```

It works fine on the VisualStudio IIS Express, but doesn't work on a production IIS 7.5 server.

Comment: We need much more details about your problem.

Comment: @GeekTantra stop relevant AppPool and try.

Comment: Why would you want to kick the chair from under a running application?

Comment: Ideally any piece of code should be able to self-destruct. Just wanted to know if it works for ASP.NET IIS 7.5 as well.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run IIS as administrator, then reset IIS and stop your asp.net app temporarily, then you can open the Bin folder and remove DLL.

Answer (score 0):

By default, IIS watches the `bin` folder automatically, any change to it will cause an immediate Application-Pool recycle.

You can change this setting in IIS manager though:

`Application Pools > [Your_App_Pool] > Advance Settings > Disable Recycling for Configuration Changes = True`.

See [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc745955.aspx)